# while running angular project which is populated error into the terminal which I've mentioned below properly

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TAam.png)

kindly reply to me with a proper solution. Error is shown below so dwell your focus there before resolve the problem:
**ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery'.**

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    **"types": ["jquery"] // remove jquery from here and make types array as empty
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

// after the changes my project successfully run
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```